# How to yield inside callback function?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

Please read this bloc fragment:

```
if (event is TapVariant) {
  final bool isVariantCorrect = (correctVariantIndex == event.index);
  if (isVariantCorrect) {  
    yield CorrectVariant();
  } else {
    yield IncorrectVariant();
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () { 
      yield CorrectVariant();
    });
  }
}
```

I need to yield CorrectVariant from nested function.

I solved it this way:

```
    yield IncorrectVariant();
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {});
    yield CorrectVariant();
```

But I'm curious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You already presented the best way to do it and here is why:

- As you are in an `async*` function you have access to the `await` keyword, which allows you to handle future callbacks in the same scope.
- If you were using `yield` in a `sync*` function, you could not wait for callbacks anyway as you are not running asynchronous code.

---

#### Return from the callback

As you are dealing with `Future`'s, you can also **return** your value inside the callback like this:

```dart
yield 1;

// The following statement will yield "2" after one second.
yield await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
  return 2;
});
```